# Magento Checkout Step Issue After Version Update

Tags: magento1.9.3, checkout-page

I have updated Magento 1.7 with latest version 1.9.3.9.

I am facing issue with checkout steps and Checkout progress.

In checkout steps first 2 steps are working but the 3rd step "Save Shipping Address" is not working. When I click on "Continue" button after selection of "Shipping Method" it's not going to next step "Payment Information".

Checkout progress section is blank.

I have also checked but there is no jquery error.

Comment: Can you check the log and errors you are getting on console?

Comment: Yes i have checked there is no error in console and log files.

Comment: Also giving response like

{goto_section: "payment", update_section: {name: "payment-method",…}}